# Using generators from Rails gems without install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a requirement where I need to be able to use gem generators *without* installing them. For example, being able to use:

`rails g devise:install` without having to `bundle install` or `gem install devise` first.

I thought that I had cracked it with the `gem fetch` command. However, my testing seems to suggest that this doesn't work. Indeed, using `bundle install` or `gem install` without the gem listed in `Gemfile` (in the Rails case) also does not appear to work.

What I am really trying to avoid is running installing any native extensions. The libraries on the server that I have aren't always there in terms of what the gems need. But I still would like to be able to run the generators.

Thanks in advance!
Ben

Comment: You have to install code in order to be able to run that code... You can install, run the generators, and then uninstall if you don't want to deploy the gem to production.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So there is no way other than to install? In that case, do you know if there is a way to skip any native extension parts?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... to both our questions... sorry :(